# How programatically collapse Expander in Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, expander

I need to be able to collapse expander on clicking anywhere outside the expander area. I am wondering what technique can be used. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Expander XAML - set binding to isExpanded:

```
 <toolkit:Expander Header="Tasks" IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded}">
```

Code behind:

```
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _isExpanded)
                return;
            _isExpanded = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using code behind.

Can you please try this in the Expander's MouseLeave & MouseEnter handlers

```
    private void expander1_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {   
        Application.Current.RootVisual.MouseLeftButtonDown += RootVisual_MouseLeftButtonDown;
    }

    void RootVisual_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.expander1.IsExpanded = false;
    }

    private void expander1_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.RootVisual.MouseLeftButtonDown -= RootVisual_MouseLeftButtonDown;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the code. It is better now. However, It collapses the expander when I click on other item in the prototype. It does not do anyhting when I click on empty area outside expander. I am not sure why. I am wondering if it can be fixed.

Comment: i have edited the code, pls let me know if it works or not. :) another question is, is this empty area you clicked a part of the RootVisual?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, there is not change in behaviour with new code. The empty area is Window area of the UserControl. I created all design in XAML. Does it answer to your question? Is any way to have a method that is mouse clikc happened not on expander then expander will collapse?

Comment: I uploaded the solution here: http://cid-0c29483cf3a6a14d.office.live.com/self.aspx/WPF%5E_Tests/MenuButton%5E_4.zip

Comment: i think i know why. First you need to remove the width and the height of the usercontrol, also you need to give the usercontrol or the LRoot a color, like a Transparent color, and it will work. :)

Comment: to be able to capture the mouse event, the UI element has to have a color, even if it is transparent. removing the height and width of the usercontrol to allow it automatically fills the whole screen, so wherever you click your mouse the mouse event will be captured. hopefully i have explained clearly to you. :)